# How can I translate string templates in Metatag module?

Tags: meta-tags

I use Metatag module. How can I set different string templates for each site language? Or translate these templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic internationalization support can be found in the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module:

> All default configurations may be translated using the
>   Internationalization (i18n) module. The custom strings that are
>   assigned to e.g. the "Global: Front page" configuration will show up
>   in the Translate Interface admin page
>   (admin/config/regional/translate/translate) and may be customized per
>   language.

[There exists at least 1 ongoing issue in Review](https://www.drupal.org/node/1986032) still with Views, Panels and other 3rd party contrib modules and the metatags module.